# Gas line : does it need to be sterilized?

Tags: kegging, keg, co2, gas

I'm reading websites and I'm viewing videos where people show how to wash kegs, but they never wash their gas line. I was wondering if it's necessary to do so?

I'm asking this because I would like to use the same gas line for my keg full of beer, and sometimes use it to produce sparkling water (which doesn't required the same PSI). So, do I need to wash it every time I want to reconnect it to the keg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 15 years, I never have and it hasn't been a problem.  So I'd say you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, you are talking about the tube and the connector? I guess there is no possibility for bacterias to grow if there is no oxygen and only CO2. But if you disconnect the gas line for a long time, would you sterelize it then?

Comment: I don't have CO2 permanently connected to my kegs.  I hook it up as needed and I don't do ant sanitation of the gas line.  BTW, homebrewers don't sterilize...we sanitize.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I used a bad translation from the french word ;) Thank you again for your reply!